# Passing multiple parameters from controller to service angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi I am trying to figure out how to pass multiple ids to the service from my controller.

In my controller I am calling the service with two parameters, t1 and t2

```
  projEstimatesRepository.updateEstimate.update({ id: t1 }, function(data) {
                    alert("Estimates have been added sucessfully");
                });
```

In my factory I have

```
updateEstimate: $resource('/api/estimates/P_estimate/:id', {id:'@id'}, {update: {method: 'PUT'}})
```

It works fine. Except I need to pass t1 and t2 from controller to the service. 
Please let me know how to pass them Thanks

Comment: How would it change the resource url?

Comment: Thats what I am asking for is how to add second parameter in controller and resource urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it as you did with `id`:

```
updateEstimate: $resource('/api/estimates/P_estimate/:id/:id2', {id:'@id', id2:'@id2'}, {update: {method: 'PUT'}})
```

and then call as:

```
projEstimatesRepository.updateEstimate.update({ id: t1, id2: t2 })
```